# How to disable WSL password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, windows-subsystem-for-linux, root

I feel there is no need for a password on WSL because it is already protected from my Windows account. Nobody could use my WSL without first knowing my Windows password.

How can I disable the WSL password? I have tried `passwd` but it does not accept a `NULL` password.

Comment: `passwd -d` is the standard way to delete a password on Linux. Can't remember if that worked without consequences on WSL.

Comment: For some reason, `passwd -d` doesn't work: `sudo` still asks for the password after that, and because there is none, you're locked out. Just had to [reset my password](https://winaero.com/blog/reset-password-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/) by logging in as root because of this.

Comment: **This is _not recommended_...** `sudo` should always require a password.  The password isn't there just to prevent others from logging in to your WSL environment, it's also to prevent unauthorized privilege escalation.  Please use google to understand why this is never recommened for Linux, unless it's a Single User OS where the only login account is `root`

Comment: @JW0914 Could you give me an example of some harm in WSL ? I don't think you can do privilege escalation.

Comment: @nowox I think you're right and WSL2 (unless you run it as admin) can't, even as sudo, do anything a user process can't do.

Comment: @JW0914 You can run `wsl.exe -u root` to get root with a password anyway.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In wsl add **your username** to a sudo config file.

Replace `MY_USERNAME` below to your username name.

`sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/MY_USERNAME`

add the following line:

`MY_USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

If you don't replace `MY_USERNAME` with the target username you will receive an error `no valid sudoers sources found`.

Comment: It works like a charm! Tons of thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the file by hand there is a dedicated tool (`visudo`) on linux that is the recommended way for modifying sudo access.

`sudo visudo`

or, if you want to use e.g. the editor nano, call

`sudo EDITOR=nano visudo`

Then you have 2 choices:

---

1. ###### Easy way

You can turn off the password check for all users in the sudo group. To do that, find the line that starts with

`%sudo`

and replace it with

`%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Done.

---

2. ###### Alternative way

Alternatively you can turn off the password check for a specific user. Here it is important that you add your new entry at the very last line. Otherwise it might fail, as you can read in `man sudoers`:

```
When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.  Where there are multiple matches, the last
       match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).
```

So, add the following line as the **very last line in the file**. Do not forget to replace *$USER* with your username:

```
$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

You can find your username by calling `echo $USER` on the command line in case of doubt.